# About serial port software for CP2102 from silicon labs

Tags: usbserial

I bought transparent RF modules DRF1212D10 and UART-USB convertor board from Dorji applied technologies. However the USB convertor board uses CP2102 chips and the RF module needs the RTS pin of CP2102 to be controlled in order to work in normal mode. I have tried several serial port monitor software but there is no RTS control option in the software interface.

I really appreciate if somebody knows which software has such option. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). There you can set *Connection type* to Serial and in *Category* view: Connection->Serial->`Flow control` to `RTS/CTS`.